# Microsoft Teams Bot OAuth Flow Questions

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, botframework, office365, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am creating an MS Teams messaging bot through Developer Portal and just relying on the bot messaging bot endpoint of my bot to send/receive messages. I also need OAuth flow for users to login to my website and map that login to the MS Teams user

Documentation:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/auth-flow-bot

I have some questions:

1. It looks like the 'start OAuth page' and 'callback OAuth page' both utilize MS Teams libraries/packages to call initialize and `microsoftTeams.authentication.notifySuccess("{{verificationCode}}");` Is there any rest API endpoint we can call to replicate this behavior or execute these flows? Or is there a java equivalent if we don't want to do all this in javascript?
2. Can we host the 'start OAuth page' and 'callback OAuth page' in our servers (i.e. not on Azure or Microsoft resources but on our website domain like mywebsite.com/start_oauth and mywebsite.com/callback_oauth)? And if so, is there any documentation for this?
3. If yes to #2, is there any additional work to be done for hosting these pages in our servers?

Comment: I don't know enough about your topic to answer any specific questions. However, I would suggest you look at utilizing the [Microsoft Graph Java SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdk-installation#install-the-microsoft-graph-java-sdk). From there you can manage [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts) with MS resources, including Teams.

Comment: You can implement [SSO](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/what-is-single-sign-on) into your web site. This [doc](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-web-app?tabs=html%2CHTML) shows how to do this via Graph. You can also setup SSO from within a [Teams tab](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/build-a-microsoft-teams-sso-tab?tabs=unpkg%2CHTML) to authenticate with an app/site, or thru a [provider](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/providers/providers), including using existing authentication code.

Comment: Hi @StevenKanberg, thank you!

Did more investigation and yea looks like I can host these pages anywhere. It's just that as long as in the OAuth pop-up in MS Teams, it can access these pages then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on answer. It looks like I can host these pages anywhere. The MS Teams OAuth flow opens a pop-up for sign-in in MS Teams and as long as that pop-up can redirect to these pages, then these libraries can be called/used regardless of where it's hosted